# htacess com variaveis

Tags: htaccess

Olá, estou tentando utilizar htacess com variais, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

meu htacess ta assim

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^$ /site/
RewriteRule ^index$ /site/index.php
RewriteRule ^continue/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /site/continue.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

porem o continue não funciona, da 404.

e para redirecionar para essa pagina está assim

```
header("Location: ../continue/".$id);
```

Comment: o intuito é redirecionar tudo para uma pasta '/site/'?

Comment: Não necessariamente relacionado ao problema, mas evite caminhos relativos no location. O ideal é sempre usar o caminho completo `header('Location: //example.com/caminho/caminho/'.$id);` (apesar da rfc7231 ter revisto a tolerância a isso, foi só em 2014), ou ao menos com base na raiz: `header('Location: /caminho/caminho/'.$id);`, lembrando que o nome do site você pode pegar do próprio ambiente, pra solução ficar portável.